# How to split a long string to multiple lines

Tags: python

I removed special characters from a text file, and then I realized that the output is a long string. How can I split it into multiple lines since the text file is a poem?

```py
def clean_text(doc):
    # create a token
    tokens = doc.split()
    # removal of special characters from the dataset
    tokens = [word for word in tokens if word.isalpha()]
    # change dataset to lower case alphabet letters
    tokens = [word.lower() for word in tokens]
    return tokens


tokens = clean_text(data)

# 50 is the input dataset while 1 is the output dataset
length = 50 + 1 

lines = []

for i in range(length, len(tokens)):
    seq = tokens[i - length:i]
    line = ' '.join(seq)
    lines.append(line)
    if i > 200000:
        break

print(len(lines))
```

And here is the output:

*from fairest creatures we desire increase, that thereby beauty's rose might never die, but as the riper should by time decease, his tender heir might bear his memory: but thou contracted to thine own bright eyes, feed'st thy light's flame with self-substantial fuel, making a famine where abundance lies, thy self*

Comment: May be you can decide  minimum number of words per line you need, say 5 words, and after the fifth word if you see a, or : or any special character  just break the line.

Comment: The *textwrap* module is what you need:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html

Comment: You need something to split by. Special characters is easy. Word count per line is easy. Syllables is hard. Rhyme is.... Good luck with that

Comment: thanks Dheeraj Sharma, please can you help me with the code on how to break the line with a special character?

Comment: @VictorEtim Why does the output include `,` and `'`? Shouldn't these be removed by `clean_text`?

Comment: I'm under the impression the original text is already in a multiline format. If that is the case, just use `tokens = doc.splitlines()` and then strip the special characters in each row of `tokens`.

Comment: @accidas, I did that and realised that I had an error of "
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines"